# Trait for non qualified or pointer/reference types

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I'm implementing a check to see if a type is stripped of any qualifications:

```
template <class T>
struct is_plain : std::integral_constant<
    bool, 
    std::is_same_v<T, std::decay_t<T>> // *
>;
```

Is the logic in `std::is_same_v<T, std::decay_t<T>>`, i.e. check if a type is stripped of anything that `decay` would remove,available as a standard trait?

If not, is my implementation missing something? I just want to make sure (in a static assertion) that one does not pass pointers or references to some class.

### Update

As pointed out by @NathanOliver, `decay` won't remove pointerness (if that's a word), so `decay_t<int*>==int*`. I wasn't aware of that, so an addition to the desciprion would be that **I want to remove pointers from the type as well**.

Comment: I don't see equivalent traits in [`<type_traits>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits).

Comment: Regarding you update, `decay` doesn't remove pointers so if T is `int*`, `decay_t<int*>` is also `int*`

Comment: @NathanOliver That's something I had totally misunderstood, thanks for pointing it out. Maybe I should change a bit the description then.

Comment: What do you want to happen with function types, like `int(int)`?  Should that be considered plain since it isn't a pointer to a function type?

Comment: Also, what should `int[2]` be considered?  is it plain since there is no cv-qualifier or is it not because it is a type that can decay into a pointer and isn't copyable?

Comment: @NathanOliver I hadn't thought of that. Need to ban functions and array types as well. I guess I was thinking in simpler terms, but on the other hand most generic classes never check this way, so the best I can restrict the inteface the better it is.

Comment: I am curious what is the use case for this? There are referential types that are not language references (std::reference_wrapper<> and std::string_view come to mind), and not being in the list of excluded categories does not guarantee almost anything about the type (e.g. whether it's copyable).

Comment: @JeffGarrett At some point I need to accept that I can only protect against Murphy, not Machiavelli. As I said in comments before, the more cases I can predict the better; the complications involved in defining this, point to why there's no standard concept for it yet. All that been said, I'd have to think if the extra cases you mention make sense in my case - certainly they can create aliasing so I'd have to remove them as well. What I hoped for, was to be able to define a "plain" type regardless of a particular use case, but it's apparent that context plays an important role.

Comment: @LorahAttkins I think the "plain" may be just too vague. If you want something that has fairly "typical" operations, you could explore std::copyable, std::semiregular, or std::regular. One of these is probably best for predictability. But note that pointers do satisfy those concepts. If you want something that is "self-contained" (no aliasing/referential types/external invalidation), that's not something really expressible in this language. If you exclude pointers but allow other referential types, you're on more shaky ground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit verbose, but it should cover every case there is.  With

```
template<typename T>
constexpr auto is_plain_v = !(std::is_function_v<T> || std::is_pointer_v<T> || 
                              std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T> || std::is_rvalue_reference_v<T> || 
                              std::is_array_v<T> || std::is_member_object_pointer_v<T> || 
                              std::is_member_function_pointer_v<T> || std::is_const_v<T> || 
                              std::is_volatile_v<T>);
```

And using the driver program

```
struct Test { void foo(int) {} };

int main () 
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << is_plain_v<int> << '\n'
              << is_plain_v<const int> << '\n'
              << is_plain_v<int&> << '\n'
              << is_plain_v<int&&> << '\n'
              << is_plain_v<const int&> << '\n'
              << is_plain_v<int[2][2]> << '\n'
              << is_plain_v<int(int)> << '\n'
              << is_plain_v<int(*)(int)> << '\n'
              << is_plain_v<void (Test::*)(int)> << '\n';
}
```

It outputs

```
true
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
```

Answer (score 2):

Yours won't work for arrays. There is a standard trait that's very similar:

```
std::is_same_v<T, std::remove_cvref_t<T>>
```

Comment: Note this trait requires C++20 support, though it's very straightforward to implement in terms of `std::remove_cv` and `std::remove_reference`, or if your project already uses boost, there's `boost::remove_cv_ref_t`